# Scroll UITableView with CABasicAnimation in uitableviewcell makes the animation jumpy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cabasicanimation

I have a UITableView that inside its UITableViewCells I'm animating a chart pie layer with CABasicAnimation.

The thing is that if I'm scrolling the table view while its animating the layer - the layer animation became jumpy and not "clean".

Animation of the layer starts in:

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
```

Using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier as well:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    ...
}
...
return cell;
```

Schedule timer to update progress of the chart:

```
- (void)startAnimation 
{
self.elapsedTimeTimer = nil;
self.elapsedTimeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02
                                                             target:self
                                                           selector:@selector(updateProgress)
                                                           userInfo:nil
                                                            repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.elapsedTimeTimer
                             forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)updateProgress
{
    if(!self.didEndProgress)
       self.progress += 0.01;

    if(self.progress >= self.finalPercents/100)
    {
        [self.elapsedTimeTimer invalidate];
        self.elapsedTimeTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

Layer implementation:

```
@implementation CircleGraphLayer
@dynamic progress;

+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key {
return [key isEqualToString:@"progress"] || [super needsDisplayForKey:key];
}

- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)aKey {
if ([aKey isEqualToString:@"progress"]) {

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:aKey];
    animation.fromValue = [self.presentationLayer valueForKey:aKey];
    return animation;
}
return [super actionForKey:aKey];
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context {

CGRect circleRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 1, 1);
CGContextClearRect(context, circleRect);

CGColorRef borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.4] CGColor];
CGColorRef backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]; //[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha: 0.15] CGColor];

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, backgroundColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);

CGFloat radius = MIN(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect));
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius, CGRectGetMidY(circleRect));
CGFloat startAngle = -M_PI / 2;
CGFloat endAngle = self.progress * 2 * M_PI + startAngle;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, borderColor);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y);
CGContextAddArc(context, center.x, center.y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, 0);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
[super drawInContext:context];
}
@end
```

Any needful help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does Instruments tell you?

Comment: Which template should I choose to run it in Instruments ? Core Animation ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't put a comment because of my reputation. This is not an answer to the main problem, but a solution to a small error in the code: If you use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...]` instead of `[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:...]`, you don't need to add the timer to the `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]`. See '*Scheduling Timers in Run Loops*' section in the [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, you can see that the OP is adding the timer to the `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. When you use `scheduledTimer...` it gets added to the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`, so the two wouldn't _do_ the same.